# Angular return promise from httpBackend.when()

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-mock

How do you return a promise from httpBackend.when()? I wanted to load some canned data stored in a .json file and return that from httpBackend.whenGET(). When I try to return the promise from http.get('mydata.json') the response is returned to the failure callback of the factory.

```
function getAvailablePackagesComplete(response) {
    return response.data;
}

function getAvailablePackagesFailed(error) { // {error = Object {data: undefined, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""}
    $log.error(error.data.description);
    return false;
}

function getAvailablePackages() {
    return $http.get('/1.0/get-available-packages')
    .then(getAvailablePackagesComplete)
    .catch(getAvailablePackagesFailed)
}


var data = {"package": "test", "version": "1"}
$httpBackend.whenGET('/1.0/get-available-packages').respond(function(method, url, data) {
    // return [200,data, {}] // this works
    return $http.get('app/home/fixtures/mydata.json'); // contains {"package: "test", "version": "1"}
}); //this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is currently, $httpBackend (from ngMockE2E) does **not** support promises within its `.respond` - See [AngularJS GitHub Issue #11245](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11245). As `$httpBackend`  should be used to avoid making real HTTP requests, but you could let some requests pass through.

**From [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend):**

> This implementation can be used to respond with static or dynamic responses via the when api and its shortcuts (whenGET, whenPOST, etc) and **optionally pass through requests to the real $httpBackend for specific requests** (e.g. to interact with certain remote apis or to fetch templates from a webserver).

To work around what you're trying to do though, you could try to have `getAvailablePackages()` return the HTTP GET for your json file path and defining an `$httpBackend.whenGET('pathTo.json').passThrough();`

Comment: I wanted to keep the mock backend decoupled from the request, so I could just remove the module as a dependency when the actual api was ready. So, I think I have to just hard code the data in the mock backend module.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same issue and my use case was building a mock of my entire API in JS so that other people could work off line and develop the UI.

To achieve that I have developed a plugin called [angular-mocks-async](https://github.com/amoldavsky/angular-mocks-async) which decorates the httpBackend and adds the .whenAsync( ) APi to it. Than you can easily mock responses and return promises like so:

```
var app = ng.module( 'mockApp', [
    'ngMockE2E',
    'ngMockE2EAsync'
]);

app.run( [ '$httpBackend', '$q', function( $httpBackend, $q ) {

    $httpBackend.whenAsync(
        'GET',
        new RegExp( 'http://api.example.com/user/.+$' )
    ).respond( function( method, url, data, config ) {

        var re = /.*\/user\/(\w+)/;
        var userId = parseInt(url.replace(re, '$1'), 10);

        var response = $q.defer();

        setTimeout( function() {

            var data = {
                userId: userId
            };
            response.resolve( [ 200, "mock response", data ] );

        }, 1000 );

        return response.promise;

    });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return promises from http interceptors. Here is an example of delaying an HTTP call for 1 second. You can add this in your `app.config(....)`

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        'response': function(response) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                        defer.resolve(response);
                }, 1000);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
});
```